# How to efficiently update state/component in React on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update/re-render component each time when from API comes new value.In my case i make API call every 5s `setInterval()` and storing changing status of my data in state.

For example let's say 3 first calls have coming back with CONNECTED so first call will update that state but other two i do not want to re-render if have same state. But still make API calls in setIntervals for updates

componentDidUpdate(){}??

Comment: use observales, that is the best way to update

Comment: use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle